# How to check if a file is older than 1 week and then move to archive folder

Tags: unix, find

How to check if a file is older than 1 week and then move to archive folder.Using some if condition we should be checking the file is exists which is 1 week older.Then try to move the same to archive

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
find <path> -atime +1w -exec mv {} <dest_dir> \;
```

Argument `-atime` controls last access time, you may want to use `ctime` (creation timestamp) or `mtime` (last modification timestamp). `+1w` means more than one week.

Argument `exec` let `find` execute some command on the files that meet the criterion. `{}` is a place to be filled with the path of the files found.

Read the manual for more criteria.